# How to make project Containing Build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

Normally the Project we create in Android Does not contain the Files like
Build.Gradle
Gradlew
and many other files in the image below.
What is the differnce to make this type of project,containing files under below.
I Need Build.Gradle FIle..!

[image: Android Project]

Comment: If you want to import your project from whatever IDE to Android Studio, try firstly to export it for Android Studio from your main IDE.It might help.

Comment: im using Eclipse for android development is it possible to do this(Build.Gradle) task in Eclipse???

Comment: Ok...check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

> Normally the Project we create in Android Does not contain the Files like Build.Gradle Gradlew and many other files in the image below.

Welcome to "the new normal". Most likely, you are looking at an Android project created using [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html). Android Studio has been available for about two years, though it only reached 1.0 status late last year.

Comment: im using Eclipse for android development is it possible to do this(Build.Gradle) task in Eclipse??? –

Comment: @UmerFarooq: Not presently.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you use Eclipse as in the comment, you have to go to File-> Export ->Gradle build.

This will export for you a gradle build that is compatible with Android Studio.

Try it out and let me know if it worked.